# Visual Studio 2010 Add Reference Fails to Show

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I have an issue with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and Visual Studio 2010 Express, when I right click on a project structure in the solution explorer, (on the references folder) and select "Add Reference" the Visual Studio 2010 window flashes as focus as left the window and then focus immediately returns and there is no new window that allows me to add references. This problem persists even after a clean install, and across multiple products (VS 2010 Ultimate and VS 2010 Express) I am using windows 7, and I have to think this problem ids outside of VS 2010, but this is the only issue I am currently facing.

Its like the references window (that allows you to pick the new reference) is automatically being closed.

Thanks.

Comment: Follow up, the problem also happens with the Import Settings Wizard. I am trying to import a settings file, and the browse for file window will not open up. It does the same thing.

Comment: maybe the window is showing on your second screen or behind main VS window?

Comment: No second screen, and when i minimize, there is nothing.

Comment: Same problem here, Windows 7 x64 Home Premium and Visual Studio 2010 Express - kind of killed my interest in the ide once again.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.

Do you have a tablet that you're using? If you enable the Tablet PC Input Service it should work again. There seem to be some dependencies on this service and/or conflicts with my Wacom drivers that caused the issue in the first place.
r3volt

Comment: Interestingly enough, I was using a tablet. However due to a manufacturing defect in this hp tablet, the touch screen doesnt work, and I have had the tablet features/touch screem/drivers turned off for nearly a year and half. Im giving you a vore because I think the tablet aspects (while turned off on my end) may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Add Reference or existing item popup is not show then answer is :

[image]

Window Button +R then type "services.msc" > search "Tablet PC Input Service" and the right Click on Start.
it will work correctly.